# Find the $n^{th}$ derivative of $y=\dfrac {x^n}{x-1}$.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Find the $n^{th}$ derivative of $y=\dfrac {x^n}{x-1}$.

My Attempt:
$$y=\dfrac {x^n}{x-1}$$
$$y=x^n\cdot(x-1)^{-1}$$
Differentiating both sides,
$$y_{1}=x^n\cdot(-1)\cdot(x-1)^{-2}+(x-1)^{-1}\cdot n\cdot x^{(n-1)}$$
$$y_{1}=x^n\cdot(-1)\cdot(x-1)^{-2}+(x-1)^{-1}\cdot n \cdot\dfrac {x^n}{x}$$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find the $n$th derivative of $f(x) =\frac{x^n}{1-x}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1031436/find-the-nth-derivative-of-fx-fracxn1-x)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{x^n}{x-1}=\frac{x^n-1}{x-1}+\frac1{x-1}=P(x)+\frac1{x-1}$$ where $P$ is a polynomial of degree $n-1$. The $n^{th}$ derivative of this polynomial vanishes and we are left with the $n^{th}$ derivative of $\dfrac1{x-1}$,

$$\frac{(-1)(-2)\cdots(-n)}{(x-1)^{n+1}}.$$

Comment: This is a repetition of the user Eugene's answer.

Comment: @trancelocation: slightly more economical.

Answer (score 5):

Denote $t = x-1$, then

$$ y = \frac{(t+1)^n}{t} = p(t) + \frac{1}{t}$$

where $p$ is a polynomial of degree $n-1$ (in x), so $p^{(n)}(t) = 0$. Therefore

$$\frac{d^ny}{dx^n} = \frac{d^n}{dx^n}\left(\frac{1}{x-1}\right).$$
It should be easy from here.

Comment: Could you please explain $y=p(t)+1/t$?

Comment: $(t+1)^n = t^n + nt^{n-1} + ... + nt +1 $. Now divide that by $t$.

Answer (score 4):

$f(x) = \frac{x^n}{x-1} = \frac{x^n-1+1}{x-1} = x^{n-1} + x^{n-2} + \ldots + x + 1 + \frac{1}{x-1} \Rightarrow$

$f^{(n)}(x) = \left(x^{n-1} + x^{n-1} + \ldots + x + 1\right)^{(n)} + \left(\frac{1}{x-1}\right)^{(n)} = 0 + (-1)^n\frac{n!}{(x-1)^{n+1}} = (-1)^n\frac{n!}{(x-1)^{n+1}}$.

Answer (score 1):

Recall the general Leibniz rule, $(fg)^{(n)}=\sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} f^{(n-k)} g^{(k)}$, which can be proven by induction. $g^{(k)}$ stands for the $k$'th derivative of $g$. Set $f=x^n$, so $f^{(n-k)}=n\cdot(n-1)\cdot\ldots[n-(n-k-1)]\;x^{n-(n-k)}=\frac{n!}{k!}x^{k}$. Then, with $g=(x-1)^{-1}$, $g^{(k)}=(-1)\cdot(-2)\cdot\ldots(-k)\;(x-1)^{-(k+1)}=\frac{(-1)^kk!}{(x-1)^{k+1}}$. So, finally, $y^{(n)}=\sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} \frac{n!}{k!}x^{k} \frac{(-1)^kk!}{(x-1)^{k+1}}=\frac{n!}{x-1}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\left(\frac{x}{1-x}\right)^{k}=-\frac{n!}{\left(1-x\right)^{n+1}}$.